# How to use Quarkus OIDC Client with client_secret_post authentication option

Tags: openid-connect, quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I need to contact an auth-server through a POST call, in which I need to pass as body an object containing username, password, tenant and role.

The [documentation](https://quarkus.io/version/3.2/guides/security-openid-connect-client-reference#oidc-client-authentication) states that I need to define

```
quarkus.oidc-client.credentials.client-secret.value=mysecret
quarkus.oidc-client.credentials.client-secret.method=post
```

but I can't understand what "mysecret" is supposed to be.
I tried to use the path of the object, a JSON, a variable name, but everytime I get

```
[Exception 0] java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
[Exception 1] io.quarkus.oidc.OIDCException
```

I'm quite confused about this behaviour, how should I define this client-secret.value property?

I'm using Quarkus 3.2.6 with Java 17

Comment: it should be a string. where exactly do you define the config property? as an environment variable? in `application.properties`? and can you be sure that the `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present` refers to that specific config property?

Comment: Hi tom, my properies are defined in application.properties and I'm sure that refers to that specific config propery because if I remove it the error disappears

Comment: This option is about passing client id and secret as form parameters, see https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ClientAuthentication. Can you please clarify your requirement ? OidcClient needs to specify standard parameters such as the grant type, etc, as form params, and it won't work if a custom JSON body has to be passed instead. It may be easier to use a custom RestEasy Reactive client to pass this body

Comment: Ah ok. So if the SSO I need to contact accepts a JSON body instead of a Multipart there's no chance to use Quarkus OIDC? I have to call it with a RestClient and manually check if the token has expired?

Comment: We are working right now on supporting customizing requests made from Quarkus to the SSO provider. Can you provide more details, possibly in a Quarkus enhancement GitHub request or Discussions ? Or here, but please update the question with mode details, is it some custom grant request or something else, part of what flow this request has to be made, etc.